# Probabilities of fragments of a molecule

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Lets consider a toy example of a chemical molecule which is comprised of building blocks P/Q/R/S.
The probabilities of breaking the bonds between the building blocks were derived over fragmentations of a large number of molecules built over a large alphabet of building blocks are as follows: P~Q = 0.1, Q~R = 0.7, R~S = 0.3

The molecule PQRS can undergo breakage at any ONE bond between two building blocks, some part of the molecule will remain undissociated as well.

What will be the probabilities of each fragment (and undissociated molecule) i.e.
P, QRS, PQ, RS, PQR, S and PQRS

after The following dissociation shown in fig.?

I've used raw probabilities, which I've to normalize to sum up to one .

Thanks

[image]

Comment: If only one bond can break, then the $P\sim Q$, $Q\sim R$, and $R\sim S$ breaks are all mutually exclusive, and so the probabilities given (which sum to more than $1$) can't be correct.

Comment: However, if what you mean is that you want the *conditional* probabilities given that no more than one bond underwent breakage, that can certainly be calculated.

Comment: Thanks mjqxxx, these  probabilities which DOESN"T sum to one, comes from very large studies and I'm free to normalize the individual ones to make a sum of one . Thus the relative values would be the same.
The molecule was treated under the mildest of conditions and here we can safely assume that no more than one bond got cleaved. In that case can you help to calculate the conditional probabilities?
Thanks

Comment: If this means that to the end of observation there is no PQRS-molecule left, then the fragments will have the same probabilities as these of the respective breakage.

Comment: Some Intact PQRS molecule will be left after dissociation

Comment: Then probably you should revise the problem and consider dissociation rate instead of probabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to make this question precise is to assume the breakage probabilities for each individual bond are as given (and that bonds break independently of one another), and then to calculate the breakage probabilities in $PQRS$ *given that* at most one breakage occurred.  The probability of at most one breakage is
$$
P[n_b \le 1] = P[PQRS]+P[P/QRS]+P[PQ/RS]+P[P/QRS]\\ =0.9\cdot0.3\cdot 0.7 + \mathbf{0.1}\cdot0.3\cdot0.7 + 0.9\cdot\mathbf{0.7}\cdot0.7+0.9\cdot0.3\cdot\mathbf{0.3} = 0.732.
$$
(The probability of exactly two breakages is
$$
P[n_b=2] = P[P/Q/RS]+P[P/QR/S]+P[PQ/R/S]\\=\mathbf{0.1}\cdot\mathbf{0.7}\cdot 0.7 + \mathbf{0.1}\cdot 0.3 \cdot \mathbf{0.3} + 0.9\cdot\mathbf{0.7}\cdot \mathbf{0.3}=0.247,
$$
and the probability of all three is $P[n_b=3]=\mathbf{0.1}\cdot \mathbf{0.7} \cdot \mathbf{0.3} = 0.021$; these sum to $1$ as they should.)

So, given that at most one breakage occurs, the probabilities are:
$$
P[PQRS \;\vert\; n_b \le1]=\frac{P[PQRS]}{P[n_b \le 1]}=\frac{63}{244} \\
P[P/QRS \;\vert\; n_b \le1]=\frac{P[P/QRS]}{P[n_b \le 1]}=\frac{7}{244} \\
P[PQ/RS \;\vert\; n_b \le1]=\frac{P[PQ/RS]}{P[n_b \le 1]}=\frac{147}{244} \\
P[PQR/S \;\vert\; n_b \le1]=\frac{P[PQR/S]}{P[n_b \le 1]}=\frac{27}{244}. \\
$$

Comment: Many thanks mjqxxxx. Let me go through this